# Prevent direct access to file in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is a file foo.php, which is inside /hello/bar.

So if the user says

`/hello/bar/foo.php   # Access forbidden`

`/hello/bar/foo   # Redirect to foo.php`

So far what I have done is this, in .htaccess in `/`,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^hello/bar/foo$" "hello/bar/foo.php" [L]
RewriteRule "^hello/bar/foo.php$" "-" [F]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Putting both the URLs, the server sends a 403 error. How can I correct this?

Comment: whats the point? You are redirecting to a access denied page again, so you will never get to access any link.

Comment: No. the file `foo.php` should be accessed using `foo` only and not `foo.php`. Certainly there must be a way to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to do this so that .php does not show up in the URL or is foo and foo.php supposed to be two separate files? Your questions is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a set of rewrite rules are applied, the result is handed back to the URI parser which, if the URI changed, will re-invoke the rewrite rule set (either in the same .htaccess or a different one, depending on the new URI).

What this means, is that the `[L]` flag you used does not fully stop rewrite processing, it just stops processing the current cycle thru the rules set.

So, in your .htaccess, the 1st rule rewrites `hello/bar/foo` to `hello/bar/foo.php` and `[L]` ends the current rewriting.  The URI parser, seing that the URI changed, will re-invoke rewriting again from the top.  The 1st rule won't apply this time but the 2nd rule causes Forbidden (aka HTTP 403 - Forbidden).

So, you need a way to stop this cycling.  In later versions of Apache, you can use the `[end]` flag instead of `[L]`.  This will end all rewriting completely.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^hello/bar/foo$" "hello/bar/foo.php" [END]
RewriteRule "^hello/bar/foo.php$" "-" [F]
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end